# Why an IIS 10 Application pool is created when I start debug through Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.3)?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, application-pool, asp.net-core-2.1

**EDIT 1** : I experience the same issue with ASP NET Core 2.0 apps using the same configuration, so this rule out the framework himself. Next potential culprits : the **.NET Core 2.1 SDK (v2.1.300)** or **a bad Visual Studio update** (15.7.3).

---

I have a strange issue with IIS 10 and ASP NET Core 2.1.0 when I debug my API.

I had a IIS Website "**api.local**" with an ASP NET Core 2.0 application "**v1**" inside it.

The "v1" application is configured to use the "api.local" Application Pool generated when I created the Website. This Application Pool is configured as follow :

- .Net CLR Version : No Managed Code
- Managed Pipeline Mode : Integrated
- Identity : ApplicationPoolIdentity

In order to debug in Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.3), I use the following launchSettings.json

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iis": {
            "applicationUrl": "https://api.local/v1",
            "sslPort": 0
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "IIS": {
            "commandName": "IIS",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "graphiql/"
        }
   } 
}
```

And everything worked fine.

---

Now, **each time I start debugging, a new IIS Application pool is created** called "v1 AppPool" (and then "v1 AppPool 2" and so on) and the "v1" Website configuration change to use this newly created IIS Applicataion pool.

I am not sure since when but I think it started to happen after I updated the following nuget packages to the 2.1.0 version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
```

For reference, here is my WebHostBuilder initialisation :

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
       new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                }
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Does anyone have an idea on what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a great answer for this one. I was getting the same issues as you were describing. I updated my VS to 15.8.1 and the problem stopped. So I think the problem was with VS.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about it but it looks like it has been resolved. Thanks for reminding me about this question !